# Laravel nav bar toggle not working on the bootstrap 4.4.1 and jquery 3.3

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4, jquery-3

[image]

Using bootstrap 4.0.0 and jquery 3.3.
Navbar toggle not working and saying

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Comment: Have any duplicate jquery file or bootstrap file missing??

Comment: How to check it.

Comment: check your master blade carefully. Or comment your js or css file one by one. Hope it will works for you.

Comment: No file is duplicate.

Comment: have any more than jquery file?? Comment your file one by one

Comment: Done. but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running the following commands:

```
npm remove jquery
npm install jquery@~3.4.1
```